# Having trouble going to mainactivity after splashcreen, app crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

Hello im having trouble going to my mainactivity after splashcreen, app crashes. The splashscreen shows just fine but my app will crash, i think i may have done smth wrong in my androidmanifest but im not to sure.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.test.testing">





        <application>


            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.test.testing.ui.SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Main activity -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.test.testing.ui.ListActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
            <!-- 2nd activity -->
            <activity android:name=".ui.DetailActivity" />

        </application>



    </manifest>
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
package com.example.test.testing.ui;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.example.test.testing.R;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

**activity_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_image" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post error log please.

Comment: You should post your stacktrace if the app is crashing.

Comment: Where is error?

Comment: your manifest is invalid. It won't even compile. Please show actual manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to replace your application tag with below:--

```
 <application
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:supportsRtl="true"
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 <!-- Splash screen -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.test.testing.ui.SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <!-- Main activity -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.test.testing.ui.ListActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
            <!-- 2nd activity -->
            <activity android:name=".ui.DetailActivity" />
</application>
```